# Deleting Char* after assigning it to a String Variable

Tags: c++, string

I have executed the below code and it works perfectly.Since it is about pointers, i just want to be sure. Though i'm sure that assigning char* to string makes a copy and even if i delete char* , string var is gonna keep the value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string testStr = "whats up ...";
    int strlen = testStr.length();
    char* newCharP = new char[strlen+1];
    memset(newCharP,'\0',strlen+1);
    memcpy(newCharP,testStr.c_str(),strlen);

    std::cout << "  :11111111   :   " << newCharP << "\n";
    std::string newStr = newCharP ;

    std::cout << "  2222222 : " << newStr << "\n";
    delete[] newCharP;
    newCharP = NULL;

    std::cout << "  3333333 : " << newStr << "\n";
}
```

I'm just changing some code in my company project and char* are passed between functions in C++. The char* pointer has been copied to the string ,but the char* is deleted in the end of the function. I couldn't find any specific reason for this. So i'm just deleting the char* , as soon as it is copied into a string. Would this make any problem ..?

Comment: This isn't really a code review question to be honest. I'd say this question is better placed on StackOverflow.com.

Comment: @OJ. Can you move this question to stackoverflow please? . I thought since it's a code check, i could post it here.

Comment: @ManikandarajS I agree with OJ. You phrased this as code review request, but there's still a pretty specific question here (namely: "Is deleting a char array after creating a `std::string` from it safe?") and the code you've posted for review is merely an example to illustrate that question. So in my view this question will be perfect fit for Stack Overflow. I'm moving it there now.

Comment: I have already flagged it for close.I didn't know how to migrate the question to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign a C-style string (array of `char`) to a `std::string`. The overloaded assignment copies that C-style string to `std::string`.

```
std::string newStr = newCharP;
```

After this assignment, all characters of `newCharP` copy to `newStr`. Then you can `delete` `newCharP` safely.

Comment: He has asked this question 4 hours ago - and got his answer.

Comment: @Aniket: This answer also tells you *why* it works.

Answer (score 2):

> Is deleting a char array after creating a std::string from it safe?

## Yes